# Not able to build custom module using Tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using Tabulator version 5.5.4 within my TypeScript application and intend to develop a custom module. I am following the steps outlined in the [Tabulator documentation](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/module-build). However, I am encountering an error during the custom module creation process, and the specific error message is provided below.

[image]

[image]

**custom-Module.ts**

```
import * as Tabulator from "tabulator-tables";
    class CustomModule extends Tabulator.Module{
        constructor(table){
            super(table);
    
            //register table options
            //register column options
            //register table functions
            //register component functions
        }
    
        initialize(){
            //subscribe to internal events
            //register data handlers
        }
    }
    
    CustomModule.moduleName = "custom";
```

table.ts

```
import * as Tabulator from "tabulator-tables";
Tabulator.Tabulator.registerModule(CustomModule );
```

Environment Configuration:

- @types/tabulator-tables 5.5.7
- tabulator-tables 5.5.4
- tsconfig.json

  - target: es5
  - module: amd